# Json deserialized in entity framework

Tags: json, json.net, entity-framework-6

I  want to update my entity after deserializing.
The problem is every time for each item I have to find the specific entity and update properties one by one.
Is there any other way?
I used Attach but it only does work for new items.
here is my code:

```
public string PersistTask(string task)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var model = new TaskTrackingModelContainer();
            var rawTask = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task>(task);
            if (rawTask.Id != 0) // Edit, Delete
            {
                var oldTask = model.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == rawTask.Id);
                if (rawTask.IsDeleted)
                {
                    model.Tasks.Remove(oldTask);
                    result = "Delete Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    oldTask.Title = rawTask.Title;
                    rawTask.TaskHistories.ToList().ForEach(delegate (TaskHistory newHistory)
                    {
                        var oldHistory = oldTask.TaskHistories.FirstOrDefault(oldh => oldh.Id == newHistory.Id);
                        oldHistory.ModifiedDate = newHistory.ModifiedDate;
                        oldHistory.Description = newHistory.Description;
                    });
                    result = "Update Successfully";
                }
            }
            else // New
            {
                model.Tasks.Add(rawTask);
                result = "Add Successfully";
            }
            model.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You are not fetching TaskHistories from database after first fetch, right? I don't see any issues with it

Comment: @AliBaig I think it is using lazy loading first time I refer to it.